# How to draw a overlay view on top of UINavigation and UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, overlay

I want to show a over lay view on top of the existing UINavigationBar and UITabBar items int he bottom.

I tried adding the overlay view's view on application window directly but wouldn't work any idea.

Here is my custom view with all constraints

```
-(void)showView{
    animationOverlay=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
    animationOverlay.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false;

    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [btn setTitle:@"Go" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];

    [animationOverlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                          constraintWithItem:animationOverlay attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                          NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                           constraintWithItem:animationOverlay attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                           NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                         constraintWithItem:animationOverlay attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                         NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                            constraintWithItem:animationOverlay attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                            NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *centreXConstraint= [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:btn
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                        relatedBy:0
                                                                           toItem:animationOverlay
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                       multiplier:1
                                                                         constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *centreYConstraint= [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:btn
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                        relatedBy:0
                                                                           toItem:animationOverlay
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                       multiplier:1
                                                                         constant:0];

    [self.view addSubview:animationOverlay];
    [self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];
    [self.view addConstraint:rightConstraint];
    [self.view addConstraint:topConstraint];
    [self.view addConstraint:bottomConstraint];
    [animationOverlay addSubview:btn];
    [self.view addConstraint:centreXConstraint];
    [self.view addConstraint:centreYConstraint];

}

-(void)hideView{
    [animationOverlay removeFromSuperview];
}
```

[image]

right now I can do this inside a ViewController's view successfully

Any ideas on how to do this..

I couldn't think a way how to do this without breaking the constraints

any ideas,suggestions are welcome

Comment: "right now I can do this inside a viewcontroller's view succesfully" - so what is your question exactly?

Comment: Viewcontroller is part of tabbar controller.. this overlay is inside viecontroller so it doesn't come on top of tab bar items and navigation bar ... I want my overlay to completely cover all the currentview controller,tabbaritems,navigationbar

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with and without the overlay? It is still very unclear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: basically overlay is view that lies on top fo all the view with some transparent background color .. I can have over lay view on top of current viewcontroller in tab bar ... but the overlay doesn't come on top of tab bar items and navigation bar.. plz feel free to ask me if its unclear

Comment: @Koen - Any suggestions on how to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to show the VC modally, I think that will cover the tabbar and navigationbar:

`- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion;`

So put your overlay view inside another VC, and then present that VC from your current VC using `presentViewController:`

Comment: You mean to say I have to try as view controller

Comment: Yes, that’s what I would try.